# How do I switch master with slave and vice versa on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replication, failover

I have two instances of MySQL, one master and one slave.

How can I switch them to make the slave the master and vice-versa while avoiding downtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a DBVIP, you could remove the DBVIP from the Master and bring it up on the Slave.

## EXAMPLE

Let's make up a DBVIP, like `10.1.2.30`.

Put this up on the Master in the OS

```
ip addr addr 10.1.2.30/24 dev eth1
```

Replace your IP in your application with `10.1.2.30`, Let the application continue to run for a while, making sure the DBVIP is being used by the application.

Here is something aggressive:

1. `service httpd stop` on all Apache Servers
2. `service mysql stop` on the Master
3. `ip addr del 10.1.2.30/24 dev eth1` on the Master
4. `ip addr add 10.1.2.30/24 dev eth1` on the Slave
5. `service httpd start` on all Apache Servers
6. `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` on the Slave to make sure there are incoming DB Connections

If you see DB Connections coming in from the Apache Servers, **CONGRATULATIONS** you have manually performed a failover.

## **UPDATE 2012-09-19 14:28 EDT**

If you cannot use a DBVIP, you must do more work instead

STEP 01) Activate Binary Logging on the Slave

Add this to /etc/my.cnf on the Slave

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

STEP02) `service mysql restart` on the Slave

Binary Logging should be enabled in the Slave

STEP03) Run the `CHANGE MASTER TO` command on the Master using the Slave as its Master

- Use mysql-bin.000001 as the Master_Log_File
- Use the following number as the Master_Log_Pos

  - 107 for MySQL 5.5
  - 106 for MySQL 5.1
  - 98 for MySQL 5.0

STEP04) Run `START SLAVE;` on the Master

At this point

- the Master is the Slave's Slave
- the Slave is the Master Slave

This configuration is better known as

- Master/Master
- Circular Replication

STEP05) `service httpd stop` on all Apache Servers

STEP06) Change the IP address in the App to Connect to the Slave

STEP07) `service httpd start` on all Apache Servers

STEP08) `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` on the Slave to make sure there are incoming DB Connections

If you see DB Connections coming in from the Apache Servers, **CONGRATULATIONS** you have manually performed a failover without MySQL Downtime. The only downtime there is comes from the Window of time STEP05 - STEP07.

Comment: I don't use DBVip. I'm afraid I don't know what that is. Can I do it via MySQL without changing the ips?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps ...

Comment: This helped me, Thanks! What additional steps I need to take to change it to Master/Slave again, instead of Master/Master (I do not need the old master to be writable)?

Comment: From where did you get the values `98`, `106` and `107`? How can I find the values for MariaDB 10.2.